# forkJoin is not working without first on Api method

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, fork-join

I have written `forkJoin` as shown below.It is not working (and no errors too) if I'll not set api method as `first`.Can you tell me why?

*my.ts*

```
    let getMyBookMarksApi = this.userService.getMyBookMarks(this.page);//needs first()
    let getMyTopicsApi = this.userService.myTopic();//needs first()

    Observable.forkJoin([getMyBookMarksApi, getMyTopicsApi])
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.setMyProfile(res[0]);
            this.arrangeMyTopics(res[1]);
        },
        error => { },
        () => { });
```

*service.ts*

```
 myTopic() {
 return this.api.get(config.myTopics).map((res: any) => res.json()).first();//without first forkjoin is not working.Why?
 }
```

*api.ts*

```
 get(api) {
        return new Observable(observer => {
            let header = new Headers();
            this.createHeader(header)
                .then(() => {
                    let options = new BaseRequestOptions();
                    options.withCredentials = true;
                    options.headers = header;
                    this.http.get(api, options)
                        .subscribe(response => {
                            observer.next(response);
                        }, (e) => {
                            observer.error(e);
                        });
                })
        })
    }
```

*Api response is just like this:*

```
{
  "num_of_definitions": 11,
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 68,
      "name": "Founders",
      "num_of_definitions": 1,
      "icon": {
        "large": ""
      },
      "from_color": "#1E3C72",
      "to_color": "#2A5298"
    },
    {
      "id": 27,
      "name": "Innovation",
      "num_of_definitions": 1,
      "icon": {
        "large": ""
      },
      "from_color": "#EE0979",
      "to_color": "#FF6A00"
    },
    {
      "id": 58,
      "name": "Life success",
      "num_of_definitions": 1,
      "icon": {
        "large": ""
      },
      "from_color": "#D53369",
      "to_color": "#CBAD6D"
    },

  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forkjoin works by subscribing to all the observables in parallel, and only when all of them have completed they're joined back. The keyword here is when they complete.
The operator .first() takes the first emitted element from an observable and then complete. Probably because your source observables werent completing

Foe the sample to complete add the onComplete line just after the onNext

```
 get(api) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        let header = new Headers();
        this.createHeader(header)
            .then(() => {
                let options = new BaseRequestOptions();
                options.withCredentials = true;
                options.headers = header;
                this.http.get(api, options)
                    .subscribe(response => {
                        observer.next(response);
                        // add this line, it should trigger the completion of the outer observable
                        observer.complete();
                    }, (e) => {
                        observer.error(e);
                    });
            })
    })
}
```

Comment: What did you mean by this `Probably because your source observables weren't completing`? If so why's that happened to it? On this article where you can see that there are no such `first()` method with `forkjoin`.Why doesn't it work on my use case then? https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angular-2-http-observables-and-concurrent-data-loading

Comment: The this.api.get call use a promise which calls on next. This is fine, however in order to complete you have to fire the onComplete function too, just after the onNext

Comment: The observable need to complete to work with forkJoin. By using the angular http service the onComplete call is handled by the service itself, there is no need for the programmer to call it. But by creating the observable, you're in charge of emitting new values and, eventually, complete the stream

Comment: Excellent.One question: If I implement as you mentioned then should I remove all the `first()` methods which are now on this project?

Comment: You can easily leave it where they are, after all if the source observable you need just emit a single value, the .first() operator creates a new one that will surely complete. Remember always that, given a source observable, any operator chain will create a new one, unless you store it's reference in the same variable as the source :)

Comment: You're right.It is working now.Another question: Do I need to implement the same pattern for my `post()` method too?

Comment: Is your post method the http.post function or a custom method? If it is an observable created by calling new Observable() then you have to make it complete for it to work with forkJoin

Comment: Yes, That too a custom `observable`.Hope this issue is only with the `forkjoin` no?

Comment: Not really an issue, it's designed this way. The forkJoin implementation does have a counter internally, which increase for each inner observable that completes

Comment: OK.Got it.I have another question about `first()` method.Actually what it does? I can see on simple array kind of `observable` it just return the first element according to the condition if any.But on API call like my use case above how it works? Let's say my response have 15 objects without a `first()` method.Then if I use `first()` on such scenario will it return just a first object only?

Comment: Hope you have a feedback for above question too? :D

Comment: Yes, it will return the first value emitted. If you really need the whole set of values returned, chain a toArray() operator before the first(). If you do so, the observable will push to you an array of values instead of single values, so be careful.